# What is the replacement for $type attribute in ANTLR 4?

Tags: antlr4

Here is the example. This ($type) is not recognised by ANTLR4.

```
Number //options { backtrack=true; }
  :  IntegerLiteral { $type = IntegerLiteral; }
  |  FloatLiteral { $type = FloatLiteral; }
  | IntegerLiteral { $type = IntegerLiteral; }
  ;
```

What could this be replaced by?

Thank you.

Comment: could you accept 280Z28's answer instead? It is the preferred way (not target dependent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ANTLR v4, do:

```
Number
 : IntegerLiteral {setType(IntegerLiteral);}
 | ...
```

Answer (score 5):

In ANTLR 4, this is the new syntax:

```
Foo
  : Bar -> type(SomeType)
  | ...
  ;
```

However, for the rule you have above you should just remove the `Number` rule and make sure the `FloatLiteral` and `IntegerLiteral` rules are not fragment rules.

Comment: Ah yes, I knew I skimmed over something shorter in Terence's new book! Perhaps mention that `->` is not an AST-rewrite operator for the old v3 people? :)

Comment: @280Z28 What do you mean by "just remove the `Number`rule " and the not fragmented rules? Can you clarify this for me because this has the answer to my issue

Comment: I think the idea is to let IntegerLiteral and FloatLiteral tokens pass through to the parser as their own types rather than having them hidden behind a Number token with a type.  If these tokens are declared as "fragment" then they don't get passed on to the parser.